# Integral with simple fractions: $\int_\ \frac{\cos x }{\sin x \sqrt{1+\cos^2x}} \, dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, radicals

I have a problem with this integral

$$\int_\ \frac{\cos x }{\sin x  \sqrt{1+\cos^2x}} \, dx$$

Using substitution $u = \sin x $ we get

$$\int_\ \frac{1 }{\ u  \sqrt{2-u^2}} \, du$$

I think the next step is to use simple fractions, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try letting $u=\sqrt t$

Comment: I don't understand your idea. Could you explain this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Multiply both numerator and denominator by $u$ and then use the substitution $2-u^2=t^2.$ To get
$$\int \frac{u}{u^2\sqrt{2-u^2}} \, du=\int \frac{1}{t^2-2} \, dt.$$
Now you can use partial fractions.

Comment: You don't even really need partial fractions, you'll just get an answer in terms of an inverse hyperbolic tangent function.